# How to prevent Alert Dialog Buttons from disappearing when .setView() is too big? (Android)

Tags: java, android, button, android-alertdialog, missing-features

I have an Alert Dialog working fine. 
It is inflated with a simple .XML layout.
The TextView is set with a String in HTML format. 
SO FAR SO GOOD.
The problem is WHEN THE .setView() IS TOO BIG the dialog buttons disappear!!!
*Where are they? Tell them I love them!* :'(

### HOW DO I **PREVENT** THE ALERT DIALOG BUTTONS FROM **DISAPPEARING** WHEN .setView() IS TOO BIG?

**Screenshots:**

[1) SMALL, no problem!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MStTm.png)

[2) BIG, where are my buttons???](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYYqE.png)

**This is the java code in MainActivity.java:**

```js
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
dialogBox.setTitle("Title");
dialogBox.setMessage("Subtitle");

// INFLATING THE LAYOUT
View alertLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate( R.layout.scrollable, null );
TextView textMsg = (TextView)alertLayout.findViewById(R.id.textMsg);
textMsg.setText(Html.fromHtml("html string"));
dialogBox.setView(alertLayout);

// MY BUTTONS
dialogBox.setNeutralButton("Neutral", null);
dialogBox.setPositiveButton("Positive", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        // Positive code
    }
});
dialogBox.show();
```

**This is the scrollable.xml file:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp">
        
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textMsg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Dynamic HTML text."
            android:textSize="20sp" />
            
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Try making the scroll view match_parent instead of wrap_content.  Or make it a fixed height.  Of course, worst case you can always drop from AlertDialog to just a Dialog and make the buttons yourself (something I almost always ending up doing for stye reasons).

Comment: `match_parent` doesn't work either and a **fixed height** won't work on different screen sizes. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @GabeSechan I followed your advice and dropped from AlertDialog to just a Dialog, it was the best way! Thanks!!!

Comment: Any update on this problem??